# YouTube Player Fragment in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create a listview with youtube videos from json and I couldn't manage to implement the youtube player fragment into my VideoAdapter.

I have checked the sample codes from youtube api but I am not that advance yet. How can I implement youtube player fragment into my VideoAdapter file.

**VideoAdapter.java**

```
public class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VideosActivity.Videos>{

    ArrayList<VideosActivity.Videos> videoList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public VideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<VideosActivity.Videos> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        videoList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.thumb).execute(videoList.get(position).getThumb());
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumb;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I achieved what I need. Anyone who needs the list videos from a playlist the code is above.